# R regex that decompose a list of arguments (from an other language) in a string

Tags: r, regex

I'm looking for a regex that decomposes a string containing arguments of a function written in another language in a list of the form `argName = value`.

An instance of my string of arguments is:

```
args <- "arg1, arg2 = {{space}}, arg3 = TRUE, arg4 = {{plot, datG1, arg1 = TRUE}}, arg5 = ga, arg6 = {{bla bla {{plot, datG1, arg1 = TRUE}}}}"
```

where `arg1` is an argument without value (by convention, here, `value = NA`), `arg2` takes the value `"{{space}}"`, `arg3` takes `"TRUE"`, etc.

Each value should be returned as a string (or `NA`). The special form `{{foo}}` is the convention for either a function (as in `{{space}}`) or a text eventually containing functions (as in `{{bla bla {{plot, datG1, arg1 = TRUE}}}}`). I already have a code identifying functions and pure text. The only thing I need is to list arguments of each function.

So here, the regex should allow me to decompose the string `args` in the list

```
list(
  arg1 = NA,
  arg2 = "{{space}}", 
  arg3 = "TRUE", 
  arg4 = "{{plot, datG1, arg1 = TRUE}}",
  arg5 = "ga",
  arg6 = "{{bla bla {{plot, datG1, arg1 = TRUE}}}}"
)
```

The regex I use to identify functions is `"\\{\\{((?>[^\\{\\{\\}\\}]+|(?R))*)\\}\\}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
args <- "arg1, arg2 = {{space}}, arg3 = TRUE, arg4 = {{plot, datG1, arg1 = TRUE}}, arg5 = ga, arg6 = {{bla bla {{plot, datG1, arg1 = TRUE}}}}"
rx <- "(\\w+)(?:\\s*=\\s*((\\{\\{((?>(?!\\{\\{|}})(?s).|(?3))*)}})|\\w+))?"
matches <- regmatches(args, gregexec(rx, args, perl=TRUE))
keys <- matches[[1]][2,]
values <- matches[[1]][3,]
values[values==""] <- NA
names(values) <- keys
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GdXfq5/3). Now, `values` will contain your data. You may also put the data into a dataframe with `df <- data.frame(params=matches[[1]][2,], values=matches[[1]][3,])`.

*Details*:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `(?:\s*=\s*((\{\{((?>(?!\{\{|}})(?s).|(?2))*)}})|\w+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s*=\s*` - a `=` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `((\{\{((?>(?!\{\{|}})(?s).|(?2))*)}})|\w+)` - Group 2:

    - `(\{\{((?>(?!\{\{|}})(?s).|(?2))*)}})` - Group 3 (used for recursion): a `{{`, then any zero or more repetitions of any char that does not start a `{{` or `}}` char sequences (repeated zero or more times), or the Group 3 pattern, and then a `}}` substring
    - `|` - or
    - `\w+` - one or more word chars.